# How to replace mysql_result for a simple login system

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having some trouble when I'm trying to replace `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` in my code. Everything works except `mysql_result`. I've searched for answers but I'm a beginner so I had a lot of trouble understanding. It seems like `mysqli_result` doesn't exist or at least not working.

My current bit of code for the login, with the mysql_result looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $sql = "SELECT membersid FROM members
   WHERE user='{$_POST['user']}'
   AND pass='{$_POST['passwd']}'";
   $result = query($con, $sql);

   // If not username or password found, return to index.
   if (mysqli_num_rows($con, $result) == 0){
     header("Location: index.php?badlogin=");
     exit;
   }

   // Unique index for session.
   $_SESSION['sess_id'] = mysql_result($result, 0); //Here is my problem
   $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $_POST['user'];
   header("Location: hem.php");
   exit;
}

// Logout.
if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
   $_SESSION = array();
   session_destroy();
   header("Location: index.php");
   exit;
}
```

It doesn't work as it is. I get "username or password incorrect". But it worked before I started replacing mysql with mysqli. My question is, how do I replace `mysql_result` code in order to get this part of the script to work?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mysqli_result`? Or do I misunderstand your code? - In the [PHP-Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli-result.php) there is a user's note concerning exactly the problem of there not being any direct counterpart for `mysql_result`...

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek mysqli_result don't work that's why I'm confused and asking, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: what is $result? does query function is alias for mysql_query? try to replace all the $result to $sql

Comment: You know that it is easily possible  with your code  to login only knowing the username? Do you store passwords user can change to their own one?

Comment: @MichaelArenzon Yes query is from a function for mysqli_query. But nvm answer below is correct and helped me.

Comment: @t.niese I'm not sure what you mean, but you can register a user and choose your own password, then login with it. But username and password have to match.

Comment: @Bondenn sure, but submitting e.g. something like  `' OR TRUE OR ''='` as password would allow to login without knowing the password, as you don't escape the input you get from the user. And you should not store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: @t.niese Okey I see, I've fixed the SQL-injections but I'm to much of a beginner to try hash the password, but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query method uses mysqli then `$result` is probably a [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. You can grab the row and the field using:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array();
$_SESSION['sess_id'] = $row[0];
```

Explanation:

`$result` is a [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object representing the results of your query.
Calling `fetch_array()` on this will return the next row of your results (or false if there are no more rows). So this puts a single row, as an array, into the `$row` variable.
Finally we grab the first column in that row using `$row[0]`.

Comment: This worked great, not sure I understand it though, but thank you very much!

Comment: @Bondenn Glad I could help. I added more of an explanation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close. But you're still open to SQL injection. You should NEVER include `$_POST` in a query directly. Read more on SQL injection prevention over at [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Problems fixed in this

1. It looks like `$sql` should be `$result`
2. [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) only needs your result object, not the connection
3. `mysql_result` is serious old school and there is no equivalent in `mysqli`. I would HIGHLY suggest you use something more modern like [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Code block

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT membersid FROM members
   WHERE user='{$_POST['user']}'
   AND pass='{$_POST['passwd']}'");

   // If not username or password found, return to index.
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
     header("Location: index.php?badlogin=");
     exit;
   }

   // Unique index for session.
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   $_SESSION['sess_id'] = $row['membersid'];
   $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $_POST['user'];
   header("Location: hem.php");
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that the $sql should have been $result, I've edited my question with how I'm using it, I just posted the wrong code. I think I understand a bit better and using fetch_assoc instead, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Incidentally, Jim's answer uses the object oriented way. Since you're using `mysqli` in procedural I gave you the full procedural answer. I prefer the object usage of `mysqli` (i.e. `$mysqli->query()`) but I don't like mixing use cases.

Comment: Also, fix your SQL injection vulnerability